# Laravel + Vagrant + Homestead + mysql. Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vagrant

I am using laravel along with vagrant and homestead, the code from laravel is mapped to the vagrant virtual machine, when I work locally with the code and do migrations to mysql everything is fine, but as soon as I start making database queries like checking the email field with using the `unique: users` validator, I get the error: Access denied for user 'user' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count (*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = email @ gmail.com)"

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users', //this fails when access to mysql
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
```

Comment: The config in your .env file for the database connection is not correct or the user does not have access to the database.

Comment: config is correct, i checked it like 20 times

Comment: Can you run any other queries?

Comment: the user `user` does not have access to the database using `localhost`. Make sure the access rights for the user are set and you have access from `localhost`. Note that if you change the config, you have to clear the cache